# Can't get servlets to work in Tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, servlets

I am a Java beginner and trying to make my first example work.

I have installed **Tomcat6.0** and using **Eclipse** on **Windows**.

I have placed `HelloWorld` folder in `webapps`. In `WEB-INF` have placed classes folder and `web.xml`.

When I place this as the URL: `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/HelloWorld`

I get the following error:

> HTTP Status 404: The requested resource () is not available.

When I try `http://localhost:8080` it works fine and gives access to Tomcat's home page and I can execute the example from there.

My `web.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- <!DOCTYPE web-app
 PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd"> -->

<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My HelloWorld.java is :

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet { 
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException,IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("<html>");
        pw.println("<head><title>Hello World</title></title>");
        pw.println("<body>");
        pw.println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
        pw.println("</body></html>");
    }
}
```

Please help. I am stuck on this from two days.
EDIT:
Solved the problem. Thanks. I added HelloWorld in web.xml and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: what is the context path of your webapplication ?

Comment: I think you need to place your class into a package.

Comment: So if `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/HelloWorld` doesn't work, what's the URL that you get sent to when you access the HelloWorld servlet via http://localhost:8080?

Comment: I have placed my .class file in classes directory in WEB-INF. 
@chrisbunney I get error message and expected page doesn't open up. URL remains same. And Error message is The requested resource () is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to have for this to work is the following:

1) Create a folder HellowWorld inside `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps` directory

2) Create a folder named `WEB-INF` inside the HellowWorld directory and place in the `web.xml` exactly as you have given it to us.

3) Place `HellowWorld.class` (not the .java) inside `WEB-INF/classes` (exactly as you have given it to us)

4) Then Start your tomcat server that listens on port 8080 (preferable a clean installation).

5) Call `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/HelloWorld` (directly from browser's url or from a form with `action=get`)

6) Now it should work fine (works on my tomcat7)

If you have anything different in your configuration then that is what causes the problem.

Comment: Thanks 
I was doing exactly like that but still there was some error. Now I got it fixed by little change in web.xml as i explained in EDIT

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I thought I might lose my mind - I placed `WEB-INF` inside `root/src/main/webapp` while following a tutorial and it all broke down. Do you maybe know a way to make it work with `WEB-INF` being anywhere, but the root?

Answer (score 0):

Please put HelloWorld folder outside the webapps folder.

Comment: Why should that help? Web-Apps should go to the webapps folder, right?

Comment: Solved the problem. Thanks. I added <welcome>HelloWorld</welcome> in web.xml and it worked. Thanks for the help. Guys.